# Undefined control sequence. \Delta {w}_{i} = \eta {(\vect

Tags: math-mode, errors

When I compile my LaTeX file, I am getting the above error. How can I fix that?

```
\begin{equation}
\Delta {w}_{i} = \eta {(\vect{t} - \vect{o})x_{i}}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: I don't want to add arrow. I just want little bit tilted  w

Comment: Should I write \textit?

Comment: yes I want tilted w

Comment: No simple tilted w not subscript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put a `w` over the `t` and the `o`, just use `\overset` from `amsmath` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Like this?
\begin{equation}
\Delta {w}_{i} = \eta {(\overset{w}{t} - \overset{w}{o})x_{i}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]